# How to retrieve CouchDB replication status from Python

Tags: python, couchdb, monitoring, replication

In bash I can retrieve a json blob of CouchDB replication status docs easily:

```
curl -X GET -u admin:password localhost:5984/_scheduler/docs/_replicator
```

Is it possible to retrieve the same information in Python using the `couchdb` library? I've tried this:

```
couch_db.view("_scheduler/docs/_replicator", include_docs=True)
```

.. but this returns a `('not_found', 'missing')` error.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. I imagine that the `.view` method of your client library is not the proper tool for, it, though.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I was making this more complicated than required. Using the Python requests library makes this task trivial:

```
requests.get("localhost:5984/_scheduler/docs/_replicator", auth=("admin", "password"))
```